# Вставка данных в БД, Вставить в нужную ячейку (цикл что ли)?

Tags: php, mysql

имеется таблица с записями формата:

> id | A | B | C | D |

так вот нужно вставить, допустим какой-нть id по циклу, в ту ячейку, которая не занята!
т.е. допустим если есть данные:

```
0 | 12 | 32 | 43 | 14 |
1 | 54 | 55 |___|___|
```

то вставить id в след. пустую ячейку, в данном примере это ячейка, которая идет после 55, если все ячейки заполнены, то нужно сделать новую запись и вставить id в 1-ую ячейку новой записи. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: количество столбцов фиксированное и постоянное?

Comment: странное задание =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q="SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
$d=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($q),MYSQL_ASSOC);
if(is_array($d)){
  $id=$d["id"];
  foreach($d as $k=>$v){
    if(!$v){
        if(length($q1))$q1.=", ";
        $q1.=$k."='".Вставить нужное значение."'";
    }
  } 
  $q1="UPDATE `table` SET ".$q1." WHERE id=".$id;
  mysql_query($q1);
}
```

Таким образом мы заполнили пустые поля неполных строк, при условии, что поле **id = auto_increment**

Дальше только делать прямые запросы.